# Wordpress 2.7 upgrade protocol

Tags: upgrade, wordpress-version

I have been entrusted with this site http://equanimityconcepts.com.au and it's running wordpress 2.7. It's theme is a custom designed theme and hasn't had any plugin updates since about 2010. I am hesitant to update anything until I know if and/or how it can be done.

Will I need to source every version from 2.7 and update one by one? Should I export all posts etc and try and recreate it in 3.3?

Essentially how to get 2.7 to latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the entire site – including the complete `wp-content` and the data base – to a local server and run a test. There is no other way to know if it works.

Usually you can run the automatic upgrade from any version of WordPress. Outdated themes and plugins are not safe.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I'll give it until tomorrow my time incase somebody has any other ideas before I accept your answer.

Comment: That's going to be the best way. You'll want to get started investigating those plugins to see which have been kept up to date. You may need to investigate replacement plugins if your existing plugins haven't kept up with WP.

Comment: *sigh* Cheers @Rev.Voodoo have accepted the answer.